# AngularJS binding function to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In jQuery I could create a web component like so:

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'm-button[alert]', function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('data-message');
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<m-button alert data-message="Hello World!">Say Hello</m-button>
<m-button alert data-message="Goodbye World!">Say Bye</m-button>
```

When I click any of the above button I will get an alert with the text defined inside `data-message` attribute.

What is the best practice to do this in Angular? One way would be to assign `ng-click` to every `<m-button>`, is there any better and more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses **directives**. When you use a directive it can be created/used as HTML Attributes, Element or Clases.

Here is an example with directive being used as an attribute:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <button alert data-message="Hello World!">Click Me</button>
</div>

//... angular app previously declared and created
app.directive('alert', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.click(function(){
            alert(attrs.message);
          }); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! After fiddling around a bit I got it working perfectly